# how to dynamically apply Multiple CSS files as per URL Param value in typescript or in Javascript

Tags: css, angular

I have written the code for getting the URL param value

```js
export class RedirectingComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params=>
      {
        let color=params.get('color');
        console.log(color);
        if(color)
        {
          if(color=='red')
          {
            //So If the color is red then we should apply red.css
          }
        }
      })
  }
}
```

```css
Here are the css files

red.css
.my-container{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

blue.css
.my-container{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
Here is the Main Page
```

```html
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <span class="mainheading">Theme Changing</span>
</mat-toolbar>
<div class="my-container">
    <h1 class="sideheading">URL that entered are processed for Theme Changing of the Page</h1>
</div>
```

Now I have to use the param value like color and change the background to the color mentioned like if the color mentioned is red the background should change in to red.

Note:Their should be different CSS files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I have found a solution for this question

```js
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params=>
      {
        let color=params.get('color');
        console.log(color);
        if(color)
        {
          if(color=="red")
          {
            loadCss("assets/styles/red.css");
            console.log("This should be able to change to red color background");
          }
          else if(color=='blue')
          {
            loadCss("assets/styles/blue.css");
            console.log("This should be able to change to Blue color background");
          }
          else if(color=='green')
          {
            loadCss("assets/styles/green.css");
            console.log("This should be able to change to Green color background");
          }
          
        }
        function loadCss(filename:any)
        {
          var fileref=document.createElement("link");
          fileref.setAttribute("rel","stylesheet");
          fileref.setAttribute("type","text/css");
          fileref.setAttribute("href",filename);
          if(typeof fileref!="undefined")
          {
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
          }
        }
      })
  }
}
```

```css
Main CSS Files
.mainheading
{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.sideheading{
    padding-top: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-style:italic;
    text-align:center ;
}

red.css
.my-container{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

blue.css
.my-container{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}

green.css
.my-container{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <span class="mainheading">Theme Changing</span>
</mat-toolbar>
<div id="theme" class="my-container" >
    <h1 class="sideheading">
        URL that entered are processed for Theme Changing of the Page
    </h1>   
</div>
```

Note:

1. Put the css files in assets/styles folder.
2. For getting the value from the url you should add the script in the app routing module

   const routes: Routes = [
   {
   path:'redirecting/:color',component:RedirectingComponent
   }];

Answer (score 0):

You can't control header tags by angular directives.

You can create `style` tags and import different files in them. then control them by `*ngIf` directive.

```
<style type="text/css" *ngIf="rule1">
  @import 'path\to\file-1';
</style>

<style type="text/css" *ngIf="rule2">
  @import 'path\to\file-2';
</style>
```

Comment: I am getting error on using it.
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/srcppredirectingred.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: add `type="text/css"` to style tags.

Comment: if it didn't work add your style code in a file and link here or put it in question.

Comment: I have updated the code @skyBlue it would help me if you have an answer